# Show asterisks or bullets instead of text on focusout - jquery

Tags: jquery-validate

I have a textbox where I need the text to become bullets after its validated. I am using jquery validation plugin to validate onfocusout. After the textbox is validated, if it is valid, I need the text to become asterisks or bullets (like a password textbox).

I can't just change the text to '*****' because I need to keep the value of the textbox because otherwise, when the page validates again, it says it is invalid.

I don't want to have 2 different textboxes that are hidden/shown because it flashes in IE and looks very unprofessional and it also presents validation issues.

I can't change the 'type' of the textbox because that is not supported in IE.

Any other ideas? I searched a lot but have not come up with anything that works for me. Thanks!

---

Here is the code I have so far (following Eric's suggestion):

I have a textbox and a hidden field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProvId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfProvId" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

The validation (on the hidden field):

```
$("form").validate(
  {
      onfocusout: function (element) {
          jQuery(element).valid();
      },
      //error is placed in the textbox's tooltipster
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
          $(element).tooltipster('show');
      },

      //tooltipster is removed when validation is passed
      success: function (label, element) {
          $(element).tooltipster('hide');
      }
  });
 $('[id$="hdfProvId"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 7,
        maxlength: 7
    });
});
```

onFocusOut event on the textbox:

```
$('[id$="txtProvId"]').bind("focusout", function (event) {
    $('[id$="hdfProvId"]').val($(this).val());
    alert($('[id$="hdfProvId"]').val());
    var isValid = $('[id$="hdfProvId"]').valid();
    if (isValid == true) {
        $(this).val('*******');
    }
});
```

All this works great except that I don't know how to get the validation error to display. I am displaying the errors using jquery tooltipster plugin. It displays a tooltip next to each field with an error. When the validation is on the hidden field, no tooltip displays. I need it to display the tooltip on the textbox. Here is the tooltip code:

```
$('form input[type=text], input[type=password]').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right'
});
```

The code to display it is above in the valiation code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you use hidden input fields to hold the valid content? That is, take the text from the input as the user types, put it in the hidden field to be referred to during `onfocusout` and before validation, validate on the hidden field only, and then replace the visual input with ***'s.

Comment: How do I make sure it happens before validation? I am validating onfocusout. Which function happens right before onfocusout?

Comment: Please show your code so far.

Comment: I wish people would explain what is wrong with the question when they downvote. How should I know what not to do next time if you don't explain??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added code to create a tooltip for hidden fields:

```
  $('form input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=hidden]').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right'
});
```

The hidden field's tooltip was showing at the top of the page so I changed it to show on the previous element:

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          if ($(element).prop('type') == 'hidden') {
              $(element).prev().tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
              $(element).prev().tooltipster('show');
          }
          else {
              $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
              $(element).tooltipster('show');
          }
      },

      //tooltipster is removed when validation is passed
      success: function (label, element) {
          if ($(element).prop('type') == 'hidden') {
              $(element).prev().tooltipster('hide');
          }
          else {
              $(element).tooltipster('hide');
          }
      }
```

And now in all works!

Thanks all for you help in pointing me in the right direction.